# Add a 0 after each even number in list

Tags: python

I am trying to add a 0 after each even number, every time i run the code it infinitely prints the value of i, which is 0 every time.

I've tried this so far:

```
def linear_list (n):
    x = []
    for y in range (1, n+1):
        x.append (y)
    return x


n = int (input ("Enter the lenght of the list: "))

alist = linear_list (n)

for i in alist:
    print (i)
    if i % 2 == 0:
        alist.append(0)

print (alist)
```

But for `i >= 2`my code is printing infinite zeroes:

```
Enter the lenght of the list: 5
0
0
0
0
...
```

Expected output:

```
[1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 0, 5, 6, 0, 7, 8, 0, 9, 10, 0]
```

How can achieve the correct list?

Comment: You can't modify the list in the middle of iterating the list. Think about it. For each element in this list do something, but change the list on every other pass through it, which changes the limits of the loop.

Comment: One thing that's striking is that you're iterating over `alist` and potentially appending to it within the body.

Comment: Note that if the infinite behavior occurs because you always append an *even* number.

Comment: @KenWhite Clearly he *can* modify the list :) The problem is not the modification, but not understanding the consequences of doing so.

Comment: @programmer `alist` is always a reference to the entire list, not a reference to the current element `i`.

Comment: `for i in list(alist):` everyone told you the answer, modifying an iterable while iterating over it **is bad**; this "fix" is not perfect either, but solves your problem

Comment: @chepner: Yes. Clearly if you're foolish enough to do so, you can cut the branch off that you're standing on. Common sense tells you you can't, 
even though it's physically possible to do so, however. In this case, *can't* means *doing so is a really foolish or stupid idea, because it screws things up*. I thought that was clear with what I wrote following *can't*. Of course, someone pedantic enough can stop after one word, not bother to read the rest, and then say that the statement is wrong. :-) If I wrote *You can't cut off your hand or you'll bleed to death*, would you argue with *can't*?

Comment: @KenWhite It helps to be precise when discussing Python semantics. There is a distinct difference between something you *can't* do (say, use a variable that has never been assigned to, because you'll raise a `NameError` instead of getting a value) and what you *shouldn't* do (say, modify a list that you are iterating over without understanding what the result will be).

Answer (score 2):

*Make it work, make it right, make it fast*

Here the *make it work* part.

You are modifying the list and iterating it at the same time.

Try:

```
otherlist = []
for i in alist:
    print (i)
    otherlist.append(i)
    if i % 2 == 0:
        otherlist.append(0)

print (otherlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're increasing the `alist` length every time you append to it, and since you're looping through it you will never exit the loop - the list never ends. You don't want to change the list, but the value within it, so enumerate it:

```
for i, v in enumerate(alist):
    print (v)
    if v % 2 == 0:
        alist[i] = v * 10  # assuming it's a number, use v + "0" if its a string
```

Answer (score 0):

The iterator create by the `for` loop is a separate object from the list you iterate over. Your `for` loop is similar to a `while` loop like

```
itr = iter(a)
while True:
    try:
        i = next(itr)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    if i % 2 == 0:
        a.append(0)
```

`a.append` always adds a 0 to the *end* of the list, without affecting the current position of the iterator. Since 0 is even, once the iterator reaches the what *was* the end of the list when you started the loop, it sees a 0, and so another 0 gets added to the end of the list. It continues reading the next 0 and adding another 0, on and on, forever.

---

Technically, you *can* do what you want, but it's rather tricky and very easy to get wrong. (It took me about 8 tries to get this example right.) The trick is to create a separate iterator explicitly, one that you can access in the body of the loop, rather than letting the `for` loop generate the iterator for you. This allows you to *insert* a 0 after the current value in the list, then skip over the new 0 so that you won't see it on the next iteration of the loop.

Don't actually do this if you can avoid it: it is far simpler to create a new list that replaces the old list after the loop.

That said, on with the show:

```
a = range(10)
itr = enumerate(a)   # A list of index, value pairs
for index, value in itr:
    if value % 2 == 0:
        i = index + 1
        a[i:i] = [0]   # Put a 0 after the current position
        next(itr)      # Skip over the 0 you just added

assert a == [0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 0, 5, 6, 0, 7, 8, 0, 9]
```

You can shorten this a bit by starting the index at 1 instead of 0, effectively pre-adding 1 to each index before you need it.

```
a = range(10)
itr = enumerate(a, start=1)
for i, value in itr:
    if value % 2 == 0:
        a[i:i] = [0]
        next(itr)
```